# Using the standard definition of support in arules

Tags: r, arules

I am using the apriori function in the arules package in R to do market basket data analysis. I have a problem with the fact that the Support parameter as defined by Borgelt (who wrote the apriori function) is not the same as the standard definition by Aggrawal. On his website (http://borgelt.net/doc/apriori/apriori.html#Borgelt_2012), Borgelt mentions that you can solve this by using "the option -o". However, I can't find any information as to how to implement this in R. Can anyone help, please?

Thank you!

Comment: there are a lot of functions in the `arules` package.  Which one are you using.  could you share a sample of your code and/or data?

Comment: So sorry. I meant the apriori function.

Answer (score 0):

The R implementation automatically uses the standard definition. You can switch to Borgelt's definition using the parameter argument in the apriori function (see ? apriori and ? ASparameter).